# How to mock an import with jest

Tags: unit-testing, import, jestjs

I have a small `redux` middleware like so

```js
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL } from '../actions/login-redirect';
    
export default store => next => action => {
    
  if (action.type === REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL) {
    hashHistory.push(store.getState().loginRedirectUrl);
  }

  return next(action)
}
```

Which I want to test now. As you can see in line 1 I am importing `hashHistory` and use it later on. This I want to test (the call to `hashHistory`). To do that I would have to mock `hashHistory`, but I don't know how. I am using `jest`:

```js
import { REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL } from '../actions/login-redirect';
import redirectMiddleware from './redirect-after-login';

describe('redirect after login middleware', () => {
    
  function setup() {
    const store = {
      subscribe: () => {},
      dispatch: () => {},
      getState: () => ({})
    };
    const next = jest.fn();
    const action = { type: REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL };
    return { store, next, action };
  }
        
  it('should push the redirect URL to the hashHistory', () => {
    // How to test it?
  })
    
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mock the `react-router` module like this:

```js
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL } from '../actions/login-redirect';
import redirectMiddleware from './redirect-after-login';
    
jest.mock('react-router', () => ({hashHistory: { push: jest.fn()}}))

describe('redirect after login middleware', () => {  
  function setup() {
    const store = {
      subscribe: () => {},
      dispatch: () => {},
      getState: () => ({loginRedirectUrl: 'someLoginRedirectUrl'})
    };
    const next = jest.fn();
    const action = { type: REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL };
    return { store, next, action };
  }

  it('should push the redirect URL to the hashHistory', () => {
    const { store, next, action } = setup()
    redirectMiddleware(store)(next)(action)

    expect(hashHistory.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('someLoginRedirectUrl')
  })
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you!